# Spring Integration and IBM MQ

Tags: java, spring, spring-integration, ibm-mq, project-reactor

help i try to connected with Spring Integration Ibm mq, what i doing:

```
public Publisher<Message<String>> jmsReactiveSource() {
        return IntegrationFlows
                .from(Jms.messageDrivenChannelAdapter(ibmConnectionFactory)
                        .destination("DEV.QUEUE.1"))
                .channel(MessageChannels.queue())
                .log(org.springframework.integration.handler.LoggingHandler.Level.DEBUG)
                .log()
                .toReactivePublisher();
    }

    @GetMapping("/event")
    public Mono<String> getEvent() {
        return Mono.from(jmsReactiveSource())
                .log()
                .map (Message::getPayload);
    }
    

    @GetMapping("/pub")
    public void produce() {
        jmsTemplateIbm.convertAndSend("DEV.QUEUE.1", "MESSAGE");
    }
```

When I call /event after calling / pub nothing happens, the message is not deducted, what am I doing wrong, i need to make ibm mq non-blocking, since a large amount of resources is spent waiting for responses from ibm mq.

Comment: Is your `jmsReactiveSource()` marked as a `@Bean`?

Comment: @ArtemBilan no.

Comment: @ArtemBilan
I added the bean annotation, but now when I call /pub
, an entry of this kind is created in the logs:
`GenericMessage [payload=MESSAGE, headers={JMS_IBM_Character_Set=UTF-8, JMS_IBM_MsgType=8, jms_destination=queue:///DEV.QUEUE.1....}]
`As I understand it, the message is being read out even before the call /event
Is it even possible to release a thread that is waiting for a response from the ibm qm queue when calling /event?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See Spring Integration documentation about Java DSL: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/current/reference/html/dsl.html#java-dsl. We everywhere in our samples talk about making an `IntegrationFlow` as a `@Bean`. That's only the way an `IntegrationFlowBeanPostProcessor` can understand that DSL definition and register respective beans in the application context. The whole class with those `@GetMapping` methods and this `@Bean` for the `jmsReactiveSource()` have to be as a `@Configuration` one to make that `jmsReactiveSource()` method call as bean request from the application context. Otherwise you should consider to move this flow bean into the separate `@Configuration` class if you don't want to make this `@RestController` as such one. Then you would need to autowire that `Publisher<Message<String>>` bean into this controller class.

**UPDATE**

For your second concern about an early consumption, you have to mark that `Jms.messageDrivenChannelAdapter()` as `autoStartup(false)` and start it from your `Mono` in the `getEvent()` using its `doOnRequest()`. There is an `id()` option on the adapter for your consideration to autowire that endpoint properly. You are right: even if it is a reactive in the end, the beginning is not and must be treated respectively to not consume until requested.

You also may consider to return `Flux` instead of `Mono`: the whole process is considered unbounded. Such a REST request should be also changed to the SSE: https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/web-reactive.html#webflux-codecs-streaming